# Rally: Team status information not fetching all the needed information

Tags: javascript, rally

I have been trying to fetch some information such as username, displayname, role and capacity depending upon iteration.  The query returns some of the result for the specified project but not all for the selected iteration.  I am not sure what is causing this. You can find my work so far below.

```
function iterationSelected(dropdown, eventArgs) {

     console.log("Iteration Selected Callback");
     if(table != null){
        table.destroy();
     }


    var queryByUser = {
        key: "teamDataByUser", type: "User", 
        fetch: 'DisplayName,UserName',
        query: '(ObjectID > 0)'
    };
    rallyDataSource.findAll(queryByUser, queryTeamInformation);


}

function queryTeamInformation(results){
    console.log(results.teamDataByUser.length);
    for(var i=0;i<results.teamDataByUser.length;i++){
        console.log(results.teamDataByUser[i].UserName + " " + results.teamDataByUser[i].DisplayName);
    }


    console.log(iterationDropdown.getSelectedName());
    var queryByUserName = {
        key: "teamData", type: "UserIterationCapacity", 
        project: null,
        fetch: "Capacity,User,Role,EmailAddress,DisplayName,UserName",
        query: '((Iteration.Name = ' + '"' + iterationDropdown.getSelectedName() + '") AND (Project = /project/5564891653))'
    };
    rallyDataSource.findAll(queryByUserName, processResults);
    console.log("GH");

}

function processResults(results){
    rally.forEach(results.teamData, 
    function(teamData) {
        console.log(teamData._ref);

    });
    console.log(results.teamData.length);


        var tableDiv = document.getElementById('table');
        var config = { columns: 
             [{key: 'emailaddress', header: 'Team Member Email', width: 200}, 
             {key: 'displayname', header: 'Display name'},
             {key: 'username', header: 'User name'},
             {key: 'role', header: 'Role'},
             {key: 'cap', header: 'Capacity'}] };

        if(table != null){
            console.log("Got here");
            table.destroy();
        }
        table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);
        for(var i=0;i<results.teamData.length;i++){

            var rowInfo = {'emailaddress': results.teamData[i].User.DisplayName, 'displayname': results.teamData[i].User.UserName, 'username': results.teamData[i].User.EmailAddress, 'role' : results.teamData[i].User.Role, 'cap' : results.teamData[i].Capacity}; 
            table.addRow(rowInfo);
        }



        table.display(tableDiv);


}



//========================================================================================================================
/*
 * Initializes all the page elements
 */
function initPage() {

    rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('5410787910', '5948174836', 'false', 'true'); 

    var config = { label : "Select an iteration " };
    iterationDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.IterationDropdown(config, rallyDataSource);
    iterationDropdown.display("aDiv", iterationSelected);
}
 rally.addOnLoad(initPage);
```

Comment: I may be guessing here a bit based on your previous post that you are looking to display a summary of Capacity information for all members of a specific Team for the selected Sprint? And you are seeing data for only some Team members, but not all of the people on the specific Team of interest?

If my guesses regarding your desired output are correct - it is probably because you are querying on UserIterationCapacity, which is blind to team membership.

Comment: I.E., if no Capacity information has been defined at all for a specific Team Member, then there is no UserIterationCapacity object matching your search, and your query will not return any results for that User.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the information.  Do you by any chance have an approach to accomplish getting the capacity for a user depending upon iteration without using UserIterationCapacity?

Comment: I think you're on the right track re: using the UserIterationCapacity as one aspect of your query. However, you'll also need User data and the TeamMembership attribute as a second part, and will likely need to stitch the two together in a hash of some sort. I'll do a bit of digging on a good approach here.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will look forward for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I've written an example that I think illustrates what's needed to get where you want to go. It does this by doing two queries in a queryConfig array: one for Users and another for UserIterationCapacity for the Iteration of interest. Then, in the processResults function, the code constructs three hashes:

- `teamMembersByTeamName`: string of team members for each project, hashkey: Team/project Name
- `myTeamList`: contains User data from Users (1st) query, selected for a Team of interest, hashkey: UserName
- `userIterationCapacityByUser`: contains UserIterationCapacity data from 2nd query, hashkey: UserName

Finally, the code does a cross-walk by UserName to re-construct Capacity data for all TeamMembers, even if they have no capacity defined for the Sprint of interest. If this is the case, the Capacity is shown as "N/A".

You would need to customize the `workspaceOID`, `projectOID`, and `myTeamSlashProjectName` variables to get this to work in your environment. You will probably want to customize and tweak - it's just a rough code sample. But hopefully enough to illustrate the concept.

```
    <!-- Copyright (c) 2012 Rally Software Development Corp. All rights reserved -->
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Team Capacity Summary Example</title>
       <meta name="Name" content="App Example: Team Capacity Summary" />
       <meta name="Version" content="1.31" />
       <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Labs" />

       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.31/sdk.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

       var rallyDataSource = null;
       var iterationDropdown = null;
       var selectedIteration = "Iteration 1";
       var workspaceOID = "12345678910";
       var projectOID = "12345678911";
       var myTeamSlashProjectName = "My Project";
       var table;

        function iterationSelected(dropdown, eventArgs) {
              var selectedItem = eventArgs.item;
              selectedIteration = eventArgs.value;
              runMainQuery();
        }

        function runMainQuery() {

            var queryConfig = [];

            var capacityQueryString = '((Iteration.Name = ' + '"' + 
                    selectedIteration + 
                    '") AND (Project.ObjectID = "' + 
                    projectOID +
                     '"))';
            console.log(capacityQueryString);

            queryConfig[0] = {
                key: "usercapacities", 
                type: "UserIterationCapacity", 
                fetch: "Capacity,User,Role,EmailAddress,DisplayName,UserName",
                query: capacityQueryString
            };

            queryConfig[1] = {
                type: "users",
                key:  "userdata",
                fetch: "UserName,EmailAddress,DisplayName,UserName,UserPermissions,Project,Role,Name,TeamMemberships,Project,Name"
            };          

            rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, processResults);

        }

        function processResults(results) {      

            // Populate a hash of team members by team name 
            var teamMembersByTeamName= new Array();

            for (i=0;i<results.userdata.length;i++){
                myUser = results.userdata[i];
                myUserName = myUser.UserName;
                myEmailAddress = myUser.EmailAddress;
                myDisplayName = myUser.DisplayName;
                myRole = "N/A";

                if (myUser.TeamMemberships) {

                    myTeamMemberships = myUser.TeamMemberships;

                    for (j=0;j<myTeamMemberships.length;j++) {
                        thisTeam = myTeamMemberships[j];
                        thisTeamName = thisTeam.Name;

                        if (!(thisTeamName in teamMembersByTeamName)) {
                            teamMembersByTeamName[thisTeamName] = [];
                        }

                        var dataToPush = new Array();
                        dataToPush["UserName"] = myUserName;
                        dataToPush["EmailAddress"] = myEmailAddress;
                        dataToPush["DisplayName"] = myDisplayName;
                        dataToPush["Role"] = myRole;
                        dataToPush["Capacity"] = "N/A";

                        teamMembersByTeamName[thisTeamName].push(dataToPush);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Now populate a hash of User Capacities

            var userIterationCapacityByUser = new Array();

            for (i=0;i<results.usercapacities.length;i++) {
                thisCapacityObject = results.usercapacities[i];
                thisUserName = thisCapacityObject.User.UserName;
                if (!(thisUserName in userIterationCapacityByUser)) {

                    thisUser = thisCapacityObject.User;
                    thisCapacity = thisCapacityObject.Capacity;

                    userIterationCapacityByUser[thisUserName] = [];

                    var dataToPush = new Array();
                    dataToPush["UserName"] = thisUser.UserName;
                    dataToPush["EmailAddress"] = thisUser.EmailAddress;
                    dataToPush["DisplayName"] = thisUser.DisplayName;
                    dataToPush["Role"] = thisUser.Role;
                    dataToPush["Capacity"] = thisCapacity;

                    userIterationCapacityByUser[thisUserName].push(dataToPush);             
                }
            }

            // Setup and configure the table
            var tableDiv = document.getElementById('tableDiv');
            var tableConfig = { columns: 
                 [{key: 'emailaddress', header: 'Team Member Email', width: 200}, 
                 {key: 'displayname', header: 'Display name'},
                 {key: 'username', header: 'User name'},
                 {key: 'role', header: 'Role'},
                 {key: 'cap', header: 'Capacity'}] };

            if(table != null){
                table.destroy();
            }

            table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tableConfig);        

            // Finally cross-walk team membership by correlating the data from the two hashes
            // Grab team list of interest
            myTeamList = teamMembersByTeamName[myTeamSlashProjectName];

            for(i=0;i<myTeamList.length;i++) {

                myTeamMemberData = myTeamList[i];
                myUserNameFromTeamList = myTeamMemberData["UserName"];

                // User has capacity information - populate data from that result set
                if (myUserNameFromTeamList in userIterationCapacityByUser) {                
                    myUserDataArray = userIterationCapacityByUser[myUserNameFromTeamList];
                    myUserData = myUserDataArray[0];            
                } // User doesn't have capacity information - populate data from user query
                else {
                    myUserData = myTeamMemberData;
                }

                var myUserName = myUserData["UserName"];
                var myEmailAddress = myUserData["EmailAddress"];
                var myDisplayName = myUserData["DisplayName"];
                var myRole = myUserData["Role"];
                var myCapacity = myUserData["Capacity"];

                if (myDisplayName) { 
                    thisDisplayName = myDisplayName;
                } else {
                    thisDisplayName = "N/A";
                }

                var rowInfo = {
                    'emailaddress': myEmailAddress, 
                    'displayname': thisDisplayName, 
                    'username': myUserName,
                    'role' : myRole, 
                    'cap' : myCapacity};
                table.addRow(rowInfo);
            }

            var tableDiv = document.getElementById("tableDiv");     
            table.display(tableDiv);
        }


        function onLoad() {
          rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                                                       '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                                       '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                                                       '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
          var config = {
                label : "Select an iteration ",
                defaultDisplayValue: selectedIteration
          };
          var iterationDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.IterationDropdown(config, rallyDataSource);
          iterationDropdown.display("aDiv", iterationSelected);
        }

           rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);

        </script>
    </head>
      <body>
        <div id="aDiv"></div>
        <div id="tableDiv"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```